# RxJava2 query SQLite

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite, observable, rx-java2

In my Android app I would like to use RxJava2 instead of AsyncTasks to query my local SQLite DB. I don't want to use `Room` or `SqlBrite` wrappers. So is it possible to get for example an `Observable<List<Invoice>>` from such a query? If yes please provide an example.

e.g. I want to put the following method inside Observable-Observer pattern so it returns an `Observable<List<Invoice>>`

```
private List<Invoice> fetchInvoices() {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(JPBContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                List<Invoice> list = new ArrayList<>();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                   list.add(Invoice.from(cursor));
                }
                return list;
            } 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure you need a generic `Observable` in this case? `Single` can be observed too, but has more concise API (see updated answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. You have not provided much context, so I will assume the following as an example:

- you have some `Invoice`s stored in the database
- you have some method that fetches those from DB and returns the results as `List`

The example is for Kotlin, would be pretty similar in Java though.

So here is your DB fetch method:

```
fun queryInvoices(): List<Invoice>{
    val results = arrayListOf<Invoice>()
    // your logic to retrieve data from SQLite
    return results
  }
```

Assuming you need to fetch different types of data, it makes sense to define a generic method which will do the Rx magic. This is basically a 1-liner in Kotlin:

```
fun <T>rxFetchData(func: () -> List<T>): Single<List<T>> = Single.fromCallable(func)
```

How it works: the argument of this method is a function that takes no arguments (in this example) and returns a `List` of some type. [Single.fromCallable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#fromCallable-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) defers the execution of this function until you subscribe (check the link for more info).

Usage:

```
fun fetchInvoices() {
  rxFetchData(::queryInvoices)
      .subscribeOn(io())
      .observeOn(mainThread())
      .subscribe(
          { data ->
            Log.i("onSuccess", " fetched ${data.size} invoices")
          },
          { error ->
            error.printStackTrace()
          })
}
```

And here are the imports you will need:

```
import io.reactivex.Single
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.mainThread
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers.io
```

**UPDATE**

You could do something like that (Java):

```
public Single<List<Invoice>> invoices(){
  return Single.fromCallable(this::fetchInvoices);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response! I updated my question in order to be more descriptive.

Comment: @Fivos regarding handling nulls: RxJava2 [no longer allows null values](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#nulls) so an empty list is your best option. If you don't want to actually return an empty list from the fetch method itself you could add the following line when subscribing: `.onErrorReturnItem(ArrayList())`. This way an NPE will be caught an `onSuccess` will be called with an empty list.